# Throwing error intermittently

Tags: powershell

I am getting a weird error, and that too sometimes while executing my script. The error is:

```
Method invocation failed because [System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'.
```

The line in which I get this error is:

```
 $LineNr = $dbsnap_file | Select-String -Pattern $check | Select-Object -ExpandProperty LineNumber
 $del = $dbsnap_file[$LineNr-13] -split ':' | Select-Object -Last 1
```

$dbsnap_file is gc (some_file). That file contents are like:

```
AllocatedStorage     : 5
AvailabilityZone     : us-west-1a
DBInstanceIdentifier : test-multisite
DBSnapshotIdentifier : test-multisite-2015-09-03-04-15
Encrypted            : False
Engine               : mysql
EngineVersion        : 5.6.19a
InstanceCreateTime   : 12/19/2014 5:19:26 AM
Iops                 : 0
KmsKeyId             : 
LicenseModel         : general-public-license
MasterUsername       : root
OptionGroupName      : default:mysql-5-6
PercentProgress      : 100
Port                 : 3306
SnapshotCreateTime   : 9/2/2015 11:15:36 PM
SnapshotType         : automated
```

$check has value like test-multisite-2015-09-03-04-15. So, what I get as $del is the SnapshotCreateTime.

Iam recieving this error intermittently, sometimes its working, sometimes not. Can someone please guide me through what will be the issue.?

Comment: I think that when you got the error the select-string returns more than one match. Hard to say from here :)

Comment: This appears to also be quite a fragile way to parse the file. Does it contain many sections as you've included above? It would probably be better to write something that will parse the data into a custom object you can then work with.

Comment: Second what arco is saying. That data is perfect for custom object creation with `ConvertFrom-StringData`. What is the content of `$LineNr` when the error happens

Comment: @arco444: I have so many entries like this in this file and I can edit the file at any cost.

Comment: @Matt: Adding -simplematch still throw me same error.. :(

While runtime, $LineNr has 2 values 202, 1356, which are irrelevant.

Comment: @CB.: But I dont have more than one values with same name in this text file, for sure

Comment: You need to check the contents of the variable then when the error occurs. More information would be there to help. Also you can convert the file to a custom object like this `new-object -TypeName PSCustomObject -Property ((gc "c:\temp\text.text") -replace "\s:\s","=" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData)`. Then you could search with cmdlets like you would with regular PowerShell objects.

Comment: @Matt: Sorry, but I didnt understand it completely. But what I want is that since I have so many entries as shown in the file, I need to get snapshotcreatetime of a specific entry which has the name matching with $check.

Comment: oh.... So that is not the complete file. There are multiple entries. Have you not asked a question like this before about parsing these files? You show that linenr has two values. That is your problem. You only expect one. Its completely relevant.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89299/discussion-between-serverstackqns-and-matt).

Comment: Thanks Matt.. My bad.. I was creating a single file with same data twice in different locations within script.. :( Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like CB was saying `Select-String` will return all matches. You were *expecting* only one and the code was built around that assumption. The error you are getting is fairly explicit.

```
[System.Object[]] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'
```

You were trying to subtract 13 from an object instead of an integer. As discussed in chat it turned out the issue was your source file had a double of data.

The solution in this case was to clean your source. If you are comfortable with assumptions you can also address this issue by updating the `select`

```
$LineNr = $dbsnap_file | Select-String -Pattern $check | Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty LineNumber
```

That will ensure only one is returned. Caveat being you are ignoring real data. So verify the source and the contents of the `$LineNr` are the solutions I would recommend here.